# Change RF Receiver Frequency by Antenna Length

Tags: rf

This may be a very stupid question, but I have got me one of those cheap 433 MHz RF modules for the Arduino. 
I'm wondering if I can vary the receiver's frequency by simply changing the length of the antenna? Or does the circuit limit the frequency band to 433 MHz?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, changing the antenna length will only change the resonant frequency of the antenna circuit. That is, it will affect the sensitivity of the receiver, but won't actually change the frequency that the receiver "listens" to.